# RemoteDataError: No data fetched for symbol using YahooDailyReader

Tags: python

```
import streamlit as st
st.title("Real-time Stock Price Data")
a = st.text_input("Enter Any Company >>:")
data = web.DataReader(name=a, data_source='yahoo', start=start_date, end=end_date)
```

Comment: We can't possibly help unless you tell us what company name you used, and the start date, and the end date.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.